# What does the | operator do when it appears in the md5() parameters?

Tags: php, parameters, operators, md5, or-operator

In a piece of code originally not written by me, I found this:

```
md5($variable1|$variable2|$variable3)
```

I know the code is encrypting something using `md5`. What I am trying to understand is what the `|` operator is doing when used in this way.

UPDATE 1: It is not concatenating of course. It would make sense to me something like this:

```
$finalString = $variable1.$variable2.$variable3;
md5($finalString);
```

But `|` is the OR operator. I am trying to understand what `md5($variable1|$variable2|$variable3)` does, using the `|` operator as part of the parameters within the `md5()` method. This is PHP code by the way.

Comment: What kind of values do `$variable1` (and so on) contain? `|` is a _bitwise_ OR so if they are numeric values it may operate exactly as expected.

Comment: `$variable1` and `$variable2` are numeric IDs such as `2432` and `3234322`. `$variable3` is a random string such as `adtw2GEt4PrPghhfLApae`.

Comment: I think I understand now. As a bitwise OR, what it does is simply to make the encrypted value even more difficult to decipher because it is not simply relying on the `md5()` encryption of a single variable but it does a bitwise OR with a combination of multiple variables, making the encrypted string even more difficult to decipher.

Comment: There is no encryption in your question, only hashing.

Comment: @JörgWMittag You are right. Only hashing because what is encrypted cannot be decrypted.

Comment: But why using `md5($variable1|$variable2|$variable3)` and not `md5($variable1.$variable2.$variable3)`? I know I would have to ask the developer who wrote that code but that person is not around anymore. I am wondering what would be safer for hashing to simply concatenate different variables and then apply the `md5` hash or some other hash option, or use the OR operator like this: `md5($variable1|$variable2|$variable3)`.

Comment: It seems like the original programmer was confused when they wrote this.

Comment: @Barmar See my comment to @MartinParkin's answer. It looks like I misundersthood data types and all `$variable1`, `$variable2` and `$variable3` were strings, in which case it would make sense to use the OR operator in the parameters for the `md5()` method.

Comment: See my response to your comment. In this context there's no difference between `123` and `'123'`.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah. I will test it with values to see output because maybe the original programmer misunderstood data types or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipe operator `|` indicates that a *bitwise* OR is taking place between your three variables.

However, if `$variable3` is textual as you indicate, then I do not understand why you would be doing this.

Take a look at the code below. It utilises the example data you posted in the comments:

```
$variable1 = 2432;
$variable2 = 3234322;
$variable3 = 'adtw2GEt4PrPghhfLApae';

echo '1: ' . $variable1 . '<br />';
echo '2: ' . $variable2 . '<br />';
echo '3: ' . $variable3 . '<br /><br />';

echo '1|2: ' . ($variable1 | $variable2) . '<br />';
echo '1|2|3: ' . ($variable1 | $variable2 | $variable3) . '<br /><br />';

echo '1.2: ' . ($variable1 . $variable2) . '<br />';
echo '1.2.3: ' . ($variable1 . $variable2 . $variable3) . '<br /><br />';

echo 'md5 1|2|3: ' . md5($variable1|$variable2|$variable3) . '<br />';
echo 'md5 1.2.3: ' . md5($variable1.$variable2.$variable3) . '<br />';
```

You'll see straight away that `1|2` gives the same result as `1|2|3`, meaining that the second bitwise OR does nothing (because it is a string):

```
1|2: 3234706
1|2|3: 3234706
```

If you treated all three variables as a string then you will get a totally different MD5 hash, as you'd expect:

```
md5 1|2|3: fdea81fcefba5a598cf3124d7dbf3854
md5 1.2.3: 8cc6383034ed459ad7a135fcb8cb86de
```

So `md5($variable1|$variable2|$variable3);` is the same as `md5(3234706);` (which is just `$variable1|$variable2`) and doesn't even use the third variable.

**MD5 is not encryption:** I notice that you mentioned encryption in the comments. MD5 is not encryption, it is a hashing algorithm, which is altogether different.

Comment: I see. In the code I receive `$variable1` and `$variable2` as URL parameters, so even though I thought it was `$variable1 = 2432;$variable2 = 3234322;$variable3 = 'adtw2GEt4PrPghhfLApae';`, I think in reality I have numbers as strings like this: `$variable1 = '2432';$variable2 = '3234322';$variable3 = 'adtw2GEt4PrPghhfLApae';`. In that case when all three variables `$variable1`, `$variable2` and `$variable3` are strings, it would make sense to use the OR operator as you showed in the `md5 1|2|3` line in your answer, correct?

Comment: @JaimeMontoya It doesn't matter whether they're strings or integers, the `|` operator converts its parameters to integers first.

Comment: A non-numeric string like `$variable3 = 'adtw2GEt4PrPghhfLApae'` is converted to `0`.

Comment: @Barmar You are right. A `0` and the `OR` operator would be equivalent to not including that `0`. It would only affect something if it were an `AND` operator.